# PL/SQL time and a half cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql

**The question is : calculate hourly works pay if they make overtime. You should use a base of 40 hours and pay time and a half. My code right now just takes the hours and times it by their hourly pay, I need to now separate the pay and times it by hourly pay by the first 40 hours. Then the rest of the hours times the hourly pay times 1.5, which is only two people idno 2222, and 7777. **

**My code is:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  v_idno      paydata4.idno%TYPE;
  v_name      paydata4.name%TYPE;
  v_sal       paydata4.salary%TYPE;
  v_job       paydata4.jobcode%TYPE;
  v_pay       paydata4.payhr%TYPE;
  v_idno1     paytran1.idno%TYPE;
  v_hourswk   paytran1.hourswk%TYPE; 
  v_hours     allinfo1.hours%TYPE; 
  v_nothing number(4);
  CURSOR paydata4_cursor IS
     SELECT idno, name, salary, jobcode, payhr FROM paydata4
     ORDER BY idno;
CURSOR paytran1_cursor IS
     SELECT idno, hourswk FROM paytran1
     WHERE v_idno = idno
     order by idno;
    BEGIN
     OPEN paydata4_cursor;
     LOOP
     FETCH paydata4_cursor INTO v_idno, v_name, v_sal, v_job, v_pay;
     EXIT WHEN paydata4_cursor%NOTFOUND;
       IF paytran1_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE paytran1_cursor;
       END IF;
IF v_job = 'S'THEN
        v_sal := v_sal / 52;
       End if; 
            OPEN paytran1_cursor;
     v_hours := 0;
      loop
      if v_hours <= 40 AND v_job = 'H' THEN
           v_sal := v_pay * v_hours;
            END IF;
     if v_hours > 40 AND v_job = 'H' THEN
           v_sal := v_pay * 40;
            END IF;
     if v_hours > 40 AND v_job = 'H' THEN
           v_pay := v_pay * 1.5;
            END IF;

       FETCH paytran1_cursor INTO v_idno1, v_hourswk;
         EXIT WHEN paytran1_cursor%NOTFOUND;
       v_hours := v_hours + v_hourswk;
      dbms_output.put_line('The current amount is: '||v_hours);
         END LOOP;
       INSERT into allinfo1 
          VALUES(v_idno, v_name, v_hours, v_job, v_sal, v_nothing);
      CLOSE paytran1_cursor;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE paydata4_cursor;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

**The output is:**

```
   SQL> select *
  2  from allinfo1;

IDNO NAME                 HOURS JO        PAY      OTPAY
---- --------------- ---------- -- ---------- ----------
1111 Ann French              45 S        1442
2222 Robert Costa            61 H        2700
3333 Linda Ames              40 H        2000
4444 Scott Brooks            43 S        1500
5555 Susan Ash               40 S        1096
6666 James Smith             44 S        1058
7777 Mary Jones              45 H        1440
8888 John Morse              40 H        1560
```

**Reference table:**

```
SQL> select *
  2  from paydata4;

IDNO NAME                      J     SALARY      PAYHR
---- ------------------------- - ---------- ----------
1111 Ann French                S      75000          0
2222 Robert Costa              H          0         45
3333 Linda Ames                H          0         50
4444 Scott Brooks              S      78000          0
5555 Susan Ash                 S      57000          0
6666 James Smith               S      55000          0
7777 Mary Jones                H          0         36
8888 John Morse                H          0         39
```

**Expected Output is:**

```
SQL> select *
  2  from allinfo1;

IDNO NAME                 HOURS JO        PAY      
---- --------------- ---------- -- ---------- 
1111 Ann French              45 S        1442
2222 Robert Costa            61 H        3218
3333 Linda Ames              40 H        2000
4444 Scott Brooks            43 S        1500
5555 Susan Ash               40 S        1096
6666 James Smith             44 S        1058
7777 Mary Jones              45 H        1710
8888 John Morse              40 H        1560
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't over-complicate. You calculation just needs to add an extra half salary to all hours over 40 right?

So once you have you pay rate and hours, you just

```
 v_sal :=  (v_pay * v_hours) + ((v_pay * 0.5) * GREATEST(0, v_hours - 40));
```

If v_hours < 40 the second clause will wind up as v_pay * 0.5 * 0 = 0

Comment: thanks I'll try the adaptation when I get home from work, I know the logic on what I had to do I just could not spit it out...I guess that's the growing pains.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need PL/SQL block? All this work could be done with only one statement like this:

```
insert into allinfo1 (idno, name, hours, jo, pay)
select p1.idno, p1.name, p1.jobcode, p1.payhr, 
       -- here you calculate how much to pay
       case when jobcode = 'H' and p1.payhr > 40 then ...
            when jobcode = 'H' and p1.payhr < 40 then ...
            ...
       else ... end pay
  from paydata4 p1, paytran1 p2
 where p1.idno = p2.idno;
```

It is not exact code that you need, because it is quite hard to understand, what does your code do. But if you give detailed explanation (of tables, columns and formulas), I can correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your question.

> CAVEAT: I do not have access to a SQL session at the moment so cannot
>   test the syntax etc., you might have to debug it yourself. The answer
>   is designed to point you in the right direction. Also, your example
>   has numerous issues, such as you seem to be inserting six values into
>   allinfo1 but when you select * from it you only get five columns
>   returned etc

Anyhow, try this as a starting point.
I have rolled your cursors into one for efficiency and used `COUNT(hourswk)` in case the `paytran1` table can have multiple entries for each `idno`.
I have used a cursor record to hold the results instead of creating many variables too for manageability.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  --
  v_hours allinfo1.hours%TYPE;
  v_sal   paydata4.salary%TYPE;
  --
  jobcode_exception EXCEPTION;
  --
  CURSOR pay_cursor 
  IS
     SELECT idno, 
            pd4.name, 
            pd4.salary, 
            pd4.jobcode, 
            pd4.payhr,
            SUM(pt1.hourswk) AS hours_worked
       FROM paydata4 pd4
       JOIN paytran1 pt1 USING (idno)
      GROUP BY idno, 
               pd4.name, 
               pd4.salary, 
               pd4.jobcode, 
               pd4.payhr
      ORDER BY idno;
  --
BEGIN
  -- Loop through pay_cursor
  FOR pay_rec IN pay_cursor
  LOOP
     -- Check job type
     CASE pay_rec.jobcode
       WHEN 'S'
       THEN
          -- Just divide salary by 52
          v_sal := v_sal / 52;
       WHEN 'H'
       THEN
          -- Calculate overtime
          IF pay_rec.hours_worked <= 40
          THEN
             -- Just pay standard rate
             v_sal := pay_rec.payhr * v_hours;
          ELSIF pay_rec.hours_worked > 40
          THEN
             -- Pay standard rate for first 40 hours
             v_sal := pay_rec.payhr * 40;
             -- Plus the overtime beyond 40 hours (overtime rate * hours over 40)
             v_sal := v_sal + ((pay_rec.payhr * 1.5) * (pay_rec.hours_worked - 40));
          END IF;
       ELSE
          -- Raise an error
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Unexpected job code "'||pay_rec.jobcode||'" for idno: '||pay_rec.idno);
     END;
     -- Insert the result into the allinfo1 table
     INSERT into allinfo1 VALUES(pay_rec.idno, pay_rec.name, pay_rec.hours_worked, pay_rec.jobcode, v_sal);
  END LOOP;
  -- Commit the inserts (remove if commit is hapeneing elsewhere)
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others
  THEN
     -- Rollback the inserts?
     ROLLBACK;
     -- Re-raise the error
     RAISE;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Comment: It's a work in progress, I know the logic on what I had to do I just could not spit it out...I guess that's the growing pains.